# Plot data from several columns of data frame using plyr and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I have a data frame with 124 columns and observations. Part of it would be something like:

```
date <- c("2014-01-03", "2014-05-03","2014-02-04")
App <- c(0,2,4)
Email <- c(1,5,0)
Print <- c(0,0,1)
mgt <- c(1,9,12)

df<- data.frame (date, App, Email, Print, mgt)
```

I want to plot App against date, then Email against date, then Print against date etc in different plots. I am trying to use plyr and ggplot2 to output these plots and have come up with:

```
Plots <- function (Y){print(ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y= Y)) + geom_line() +
                                scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks('month'), label=                                   date_format('%b-%Y')) + 
                                labs(title="A", x="Date Issued", y="Number of tickets issued")+ 
                                theme_bw()) }
ServicePlots <- d_ply (df, col , Plots, .print=TRUE)
```

The packages lubridate, chron and scales are also being used in the plots. However, this does not seem to work at all. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong? And maybe help me out a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no idea what `plyr` has to do with anything here just `melt` the data and plot it as is:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
df <- melt(df) 
ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(date), value)) +  
geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +  
scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks('month')) +
facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales = "free") + 
labs(title="A", x="Date Issued", y="Number of tickets issued") + 
theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want it in a function form, do

```
Plots <- function(x){
  x <- melt(x)
  ggplot(x, aes(as.Date(date), value)) +  
  geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +  
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks('month')) +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales = "free") + 
  labs(title="A", x="Date Issued", y="Number of tickets issued") + 
  theme_bw()
} 

Plots(df)
```

Comment: Thanks! so basically, a small (and probably stupid) question: Is it possible to have each plot separately? I have 124 of those and want each plot to be separate?

Comment: Do i just not use facet_wrap?

Answer (score -1):

Following is not ggplot based but it works:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
for(i in 2:5)
    plot(mydf[,1], mydf[,i], main=colnames(mydf)[i])
```

Comment: I know how to do it with a for loop, was just trying to use plyr as it is a requirement to this piece of work unfortunately :-(